# Looking for references on 'non-discrete lattices'

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, integer-lattices

A [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29#See_also) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a discrete subgroup that spans $\mathbb{R}^n$. Recently I've been running into a similar sort of object consisting of more than $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and their $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations.

I think this is best seen via an example.

Consider the boring lattice generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. This is the good ol' standard coordinate lattice we know and love.

Now look at the 'non-discrete lattice' generated by $(1,0), (0,1), (1,\sqrt 2)$. This is not a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^2$ because it's 'horizontally dense,' i.e. if $(x,y)$ is in the 'lattice,' then there are infinitely many other points in $(x\pm \epsilon, y)$ in the 'lattice.' This is very different than the non-disrete lattice generated by $(1,0), (0,1), (\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$, which is everywhere dense.

These examples are a bit contrived, but in higher dimensions/more general fields, I have a hard time determining the resulting characteristics of the 'lattice.' For example, is it easy to tell how 'dense' the resulting 'lattice' is? Does this come up/are there known applications of this to, say, number theory?

To be specific:

> 1. Is there a name for the concept of what I've been calling a 'non-discrete lattice?'
> 2. Can you point me to reference material on 'non-discrete lattices?'

Comment: What differentiates your definition of a non-discrete lattice from a finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Alex Nothing. But lattices are also finitely generated subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and yet have a rich theory.

Comment: Right, but to distinguish f.g. subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we made the distinction that their $\mathbb{Z}$-basis is linearly independent. What extra property do you want to impose on your "non-discrete lattices" to make it more restrictive than just f.g. subgroups.

Comment: It's not a direct relation and these are fuzzy memories, but I have vague recollection of there being some loose connections between these sorts of entities and Connes' noncommutative geometry (though that may be a false positive going through the Penrose lattices).  Maybe someone with a better knowledge of exotic spaces can speak to that.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing this reminds me of is "equidistribution" issues, e.g., as Weyl, and going back to Kronecker. That is, in the simplest case, for irrational $\theta$, the collection of integer multiples of $\theta$ is equidistributed in the circle $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, in the sense that for (e.g., smooth, but $C^1$ more than suffices) periodic $f$, the limit of ${1\over N}\sum_{1\le n\le N} f(n\theta)$ is $\int_0^1 f$.

Similar results hold in higher dimension/rank, and in-between results exist, as illustrated in the question. That is, the analogous limit may be integration over a proper sub-torus.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, Alex answered #1 as a "nondiscrete lattice" is really just a finitely generated group.

A similar type of thing does arise in number theory. For example, in the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not a lattice inside of $\mathbb{R}$ as it is not discrete. A central philosophy of number theory is one must not forget Galois conjugates. Applying this in this case leads to the embedding 
$$(a+b\sqrt{2}) \rightarrow (a+b\sqrt{2}, a-b\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$$
and its image is a lattice. More generally this can be applied to any ring of integers (see [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Ullery.pdf) for the general technique and a classical application).

Also asked was the question:

"Does this come up/are there known applications of this to, say, number theory?"

I'm going to be bold and say the answer is "no", although I would love for someone who knows of an example to come forward. At the very least I can't think of any examples in the fields of number theory I'm most familiar with (classic algebraic number theory, modern algebraic number theory, Diophantine geometry). Admittedly I am less familiar with analytic number theory and (perhaps ironically) this is an area where I could see such subgroups most likely to be used.

Philosophically I think this is because number theory is a discrete subject almost by definition. More specifically, given a subgroup there are typically two things you can study: the subgroup itself and the quotient by the subgroup. When you want to study the subgroup itself, usually it's because it somehow relates to integers and thus *should* be discrete. Quotients are also used, especially in modern algebraic number theory with modular curves and their higher dimensional analogues. Again, here one needs the group to be discrete because there is a geometric structure which one wants to preserve on the quotient.